# Delete blank space between vertical blocks

Tags: html, css, positioning

I don't know how can I delete blank spaces between vertical blocks. Example:[image]

I want that all blocks are located under each other. Each block have `display: inline-block`. I experimented with position and display, but all in vain.

Comment: use height width cleverly using % and you can achieve it easily, Give the file path of the image or video so that it will be clear.

Comment: That is not easily achievable with CSS only when your content is dynamic – that’s why solutions like f.e. jQuery Masonry were invented.

Comment: CBroe, thank you, seems it's really what I need. I try to use this plugin now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please send me the URL First,You can use [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

you must embed in in your website,and you can use CSS techniques to fix the issue

you can see the demo in [here](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/infinite-scroll.html)

and please note that, you can define a class for those object and interact with them using CSS code,you can define specific height for them,please note that the images are not loaded correctly in your web page and you have to fix them first 
if you have any other question,please feel free to ask me.

Good Luck.

PS: there are some other alternatives exists for the jQuery Masonry,one is [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and the other is a CSS-Driven tool Called [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/)